# Windows API to disable Filter Keys dialog?

Tags: windows, winapi, keyboard

My C++ game allows users to hold down the shift key for a speed boost, but after 8 seconds this causes an annoying dialog to pop up on a fresh Windows 10 machine ("Do you want to turn on Filter Keys?").  Is there a way to disable this programmatically while my game is running?

Comment: I imagine if you use XInput / DirectInput then this sort of thing would be bypassed.

Comment: According to the current DirectInput documentation: "The use of DirectInput for keyboard and mouse input is not recommended. You should use Windows messages instead."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you could refer to the Doc:[Disabling Shortcut Keys in Games](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxtecharts/disabling-shortcut-keys-in-games)

To avoid these issues, you should disable these keys when running in full-screen mode, and either enable the keys back to their default handlers when running in windowed mode or exit the application.

To turn off these shortcuts:

1,Capture the current accessibility settings before disabling them.

2,Disable the accessibility shortcut when the application goes into full-screen mode if the accessibility feature is off.

3,Restore the accessibility settings when the application goes into windowed mode or exits.

You could try to use [SystemParametersInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-6.0/aa227580(v=vs.60)) to Get and Set System Information.